# How to display date picker and time picker in line?

Tags: theming, forms, datetime

When I set the time in "#date_format", a time picker is added below the date picker. How could I set it in the same row as the date picker?

Code:

```
$form['alert']['endDate'] = [
  '#default_value'       => !empty($endDate) ? Utils::formatDate($endDate) : date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month", time())),
  '#date_format'         => 'd/m/Y H:i',
  '#date_label_position' => 'within',
  '#prefix'              => '<div class="col-md-3">',
  '#suffix'              => '</div></div>',
  '#title'               => t('End Date'),
  '#type'                => 'date_popup',
];
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Short answer: with CSS.

Comment: More specifically something like 'display: inline-block;' applied to each wrapper of the input. The issue however is not Drupal specific.